# luaotfload : Windows API error 67

Tags: errors, luaotfload

I got subtle error when running `lualatex` on my new desktop (W7 Pro Russian x64, MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit). Similar program set on my laptop (W7 Home Russian x64, MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) gives no  errors. As it is seen from attacted log, LuaLaTeX cannot generate font base reporting that **lualatex.EXE cannot find network name** `\\MiKTeX\]MPM[\fonts\opentype`. Indeed, there is no such path on my comp. `Luatex.exe` is looking for server `\\MiKTeX`, which is absent.

Running `DebugView` with various trace options gave me no idea where the problem came from. The only visible difference between my desktop and laptop is that the desktop is included into company's network through novel client (which I hate, to say truth). I would appriciate any adea on how to resolve my problem.

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.70.1-2011080216 (rev 4277)  (format=lualatex 2011.10.10)  11 OCT 2011 09:45
. . .
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg")))
luaotfload | Font names database not found, generating new one.
             This can take several minutes; please be patient.
luaotfload | Updating the font names database:
luaotfload | Scanning TEXMF and OS fonts...lualatex.EXE: Windows API error 67: The network name cannot be found.
lualatex.EXE: Data: \\MiKTeX\]MPM[\fonts\opentype
```

Comment: Perhaps your user roots are on the  network. Does `kpsewhich --expand-var="$TEXMF"` show a root with this path? Or are there symlinks or something like this which connects your user profile with the network path?

Comment: @Joseph: this problem persits for almost a year and not limited to my own case only as shows this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49532/luatex-font-database-cannot-be-created-in-miktex-2-9