# LuaTeX font database cannot be created in MiKTeX 2.9

Tags: luatex, miktex

Quite in a hurry I am trying to setup MiKTeX 2.9 on the computer of a friend of mine. We started with the portable version but the problem is the same in the normal install.

Before the compilation of the `.tex`-file LuaLaTeX needs the font name database and the creation fails with this error message:

```
C:\miktex>mkluatexfontdb -vvv

luaotfload | Updating the font names database:
luaotfload | Font names database not found, generating new one.
             This can take several minutes; please be patient.
luaotfload | Updating the font names database:
[...]
luaotfload | blacklisted file: /System/Library/Fonts/STHeiti Light.ttc
luaotfload | Scanning TEXMF and OS fonts...mkluatexfontdb: Windows API error 67:
 The network name cannot be found.
mkluatexfontdb: Data: \\MiKTeX\]MPM[\fonts\opentype
```

The issue seems similar to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31188/luaotfload-windows-api-error-67), which unfortunately received no answers. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What I can deduce so far from the error message is that `mkluatexfontdb` wants to access the network server `\\MiKTeX` which does not exist, and which I have never given as an option to search for. This happens with the current (25.03.12) portable version of MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 7 64 but I could also reproduce it with the normal version.

In the documentation to `luaotfload` it is mentioned that `%WINDIR%\Fonts` will be searched but not any network server and there seems no way to disable this.

Edit: The only vaguely related environment variables are:

```
HOME=C:\\Users\user
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\user
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER=\\WIN7
MIKTEX_BINDIR=C:\miktex\miktex\bin
MIKTEX_COMMONSTARTUPFILE=C:\miktex\miktex\config\miktexstartup.ini
MIKTEX_GS_LIB=C:\miktex\ghostscript\base;C:\miktex\fonts
MIKTEX_USERSTARTUPFILE=C:\miktex\miktex\config\miktexstartup.ini
Path=C:\miktex\miktex/bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbe
m;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0    SystemDrive=C:
SystemRoot=C:\Windows
TEMP=C:\miktex\miktex\temp    TEMPDIR=C:\miktex\miktex\temp    TMP=C:\miktex\miktex\temp    TMPDIR=C:\miktex\miktex\temp    USERDOMAIN=win7
USERNAME=user
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\user
windir=C:\Windows
```

2nd edit:
The path to the fonts can also not be accessed (MWE):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}
Example text.
\directlua{tex.print(-2,kpse.expand_path("$OPENTYPEFONTS"))}
\end{document}
```

leads to the following output of `lualatex`:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.70.1-2011080216 (rev 4277)
(C:/temp/test1.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
LuaTeX adaptation of babel <v3.8l-luatex-1.4> and hyphenation patterns for engl
ish, loaded.
(C:/miktex/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(C:/miktex/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
No file test1.aux.
lualatex: Windows API error 67: The network name cannot be found.
lualatex: Data: \\MiKTeX\]MPM[\fonts\opentype
```

This is the output of kpsewhich in the directory of the .tex file:

```
C:\temp>kpsewhich --expand-path=$OPENTYPEFONTS
kpsewhich: Windows API error 67: The network name cannot be found.
kpsewhich: Data: \\MiKTeX\]MPM[\fonts\opentype
```

Comment: luaoftload searches also the texmf trees and uses some environment variable. So check them (I haven't the time now to investigate.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: This is a fresh miktex portable installation. As far as I know there is no other texmf besides the installation directory.

Comment: What do you get if you run in a document (with fontspec if possible, but without is also ok) `\directlua{tex.print(-2,kpse.expand_path("$OPENTYPEFONTS"))}`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thank you for looking into this, I added the output of the command you proposed. Additionally I tried with the `fontspec` package but received the same error message.

Comment: Hm. You are saying the document (without fontspec!) above leads to the same error? Then it can't be directly related to `mkluatexfontdb`. Does it disappear if you use e.g. `\directlua{tex.print(-2,"abc")}`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Without fontspec and using `\directlua{tex.print(-2,"abc")}` compiles correctly and prints `abc` in the pdf-file.

Comment: Ok. So obviously there is a problem with the kpse path. What do you get if you run on the command line `kpsewhich
--expand-path=$OPENTYPEFONTS`? (The first path is the current directory so make sure that you are running the command in the directory of your tex file).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I added the output of kpsewhich; same error message.

Comment: So the problem is with this variable. I would suggest that you make a bug report in the miktex tracker and ask how the content of the variable is generated (miktex doesn't have a texmf.cnf-file) so that you can figure out what goes wrong on your system.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thank you for pinning this down, I wrote a bug report.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Christian Schenk closed the bug as 'Works for me', I will switch to TeX Live then, thank you again for your support.

Comment: Well I told you to "ask how the content of the variable is generated so that you can figure out what goes wrong on your system".

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with my office computer while exactly the same miktex installation works fine on my laptop. That is why I moved to TeXlive although it looks like bycicle vs. ferrary as compared to MiKTeX (I mean absence of automatic package installation in TL)

Comment: This looks like a MiKTeX bug or at least some odd issue. We can't really 'answer' bugs, so this is 'not a real question' for the purposes of tracking questions (as we cannot answer it).