# Error during luaotfload font name database creation

Tags: miktex, luaotfload

I got an error on a new MiKTeX 2.9 win7 64-bit install while running the luaotfload tool.

```
luaotfload | Updating the font names database:
luaotfload | Font names database not found, generating new one.
      This can take several minutes; please be patient.
luaotfload | Updating the font names database:
<omitted>
The network name cannot be found.
Data: \\MiKTeX\]MPM[\fonts\opentype
```

The error is very cryptic and is very similar to

[LuaTeX font database cannot be created in MiKTeX 2.9](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49532/luatex-font-database-cannot-be-created-in-miktex-2-9)

Unfortunatly that topic was unanswered. However, I dug a little deeper and found the real cause. The $OPENTYPEFONTS path in MikTex is set to (among other things) '%R\fonts\opentype//'

Now I checked expanding this path using

```
kpsewhich --expand-path='%R'
```

and I get the same error. But if I use a small letter r

```
kpsewhich --expand-path="%r"
```

it works perfectly fine.

How do I make kpsewhich case-insensitive or update the $OPENTYPEFONTS variable to have a small %r

Comment: I can't reproduce your error and I don't know why %R or %r should make a difference. But imho you should try to make a trace (see the miktex page) and then a miktex bug report with this new informations. Btw: You use different quotes in your kpsewhich calls.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for you reply. The quotes are different only in the post. I have tried out all combinations. I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem and tried to implement your solution. Maybe someone knows a more elegant way, but it works for me now: In every affected Lua file in the directory `tex/latex/luaotfload` (for me: `luaotfload-configuration.lua`, `luaotfload-database.lua`, `luaotfload-diagnostics.lua` and `luaotfload-parsers.lua`) you have to replace the line

```
local kpseexpand_path = kpse.expand_path
```

by

```
local kpseexpand_path = function (p) return kpse.expand_path(string.gsub(kpse.expand_var(p), '%%R', '%%r')) end
```

It expands the variables `$OPENTYPEFONTS` and the others, but replaces `%R` by `%r` before that is expanded in turn. As far as I can tell from the MiKTeX source code, the appearance of `%R` in `$OPENTYPEFONTS` is hard-coded, so this is the only way I could find without recompiling MiKTeX...